# Specify each resource type request in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to specify resource request of each specific resource type for all pods. for example, resource request for CPU. How can I calculate it in go programming?

Comment: It might be a good idea to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make sure people understand what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The exact amount of `request` and `limit` is difficult to tune without benchmarking your application. You can consider running some profiling tools on your go application to figure out the steady-state memory and CPU usage. You should specify the `request` amount with your this steady-state usage + some margin of error.

Hope this helps!